# Prolog member function

Tags: prolog

I am trying to return true if the object is in Obj false otherwise.
But the built in member function does not give me true or false.
It gives me Obj as shown. How do i make it return true or false ?

```
member(communicator,Obj).
Obj = [communicator|_G3422].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments it sounds like you're not following how Prolog works at the prompt.

If you enter this:

```
?- Obj = [communicator, gun].
Obj = [communicator, gun].
```

And it ends in a period, then Prolog will satisfy this query instantiating `Obj` with `[communicator, gun]` and show the final solution: `Obj = [communicator, gun].`.

At this point, that expression is done, and `Obj` no longer has a value after the solution is found. A subsequent call to `member/2` shows this:

```
?- member(communicator, Obj).
Obj = [communicator|_G51] ;
```

What you need to do is instantiate `Obj` in the same logical clause:

```
?- Obj = [communicator, gun], member(communicator, Obj).
Obj = [communicator, gun] ;
false.

?-
```

Note the comma, which is an AND in Prolog. Prolog succeeded and found one solution (`Obj = [communicator, gun]` and then, after you enter `;` to find more solutions, it finds no more and displays, `false`.

Answer (score 0):

some hints:

```
?- List = [a,b,c], member(Obj, List).
List = [a, b, c],
Obj = a ;
List = [a, b, c],
Obj = b ;
List = [a, b, c],
Obj = c.
```

where you see ';' I requested Prolog to *backtrack* over available solutions.
Now shoudl be clear that

```
?- List = [a,b,c], member(communicator, List).
false.
```

because `communicator` it's not a member of List. But

```
?- List = [a,b,communicator,c], member(communicator, List).
List = [a, b, communicator, c] ;
false.
```

finds the element and inform me of this fact, showing the bindings available `List = [a, b, communicator, c]`. It then waits for me to choice if search for more, I give ';' and Prolog inform me that not there is another instance of `communicator`.

HTH

Comment: proof that Obj has the list:
at(X,Obj).
X = office,
Obj = [communicator, gun]

Comment: i want member(communicator,Obj) to give me true but it gives me Obj = [communicator|_G3422].

Comment: It's Obj that's not clear. How do you build Obj *before* calling member? Otherwise, Wouter' answer is technically sound. Doesn't that works for you ?

Comment: this gives me false:
member_dp(communicator,Obj).
false.

I have  dynamic  at/2 and then 
at(office, [communicator,gun]). %there is communicator,gun object in the office

Answer (score 0):

You ask for a variant of `member/2` that:

1. returns either `true` or `false`. This is called a **decision procedure** in computer science. In Prolog, a predicate with this property is called **semi-deterministic**.
2. does not instantiate a variable list argument (e.g. your `Obj=[communicator|_G3422]` example).

The following code implements both of these characteristics:

```
member_dp(X, L):-
  is_list(L),
  memberchk(X, L).
```

Comment: it should be `memberchk(X,L)`.

Comment: @Jinxed Thanks for noticing, fixed now.